# T-SQL group by and filter for all

Tags: t-sql, group-by

Please edit my question for a better title (and remove this line)

Hi I have a table

```
id|Col_A|Col_B|
--|-----|-----|
 1|  A  | NULL|
 2|  A  |  a  |
 3|  B  |  a  |
 4|  C  | NULL|
 5|  C  | NULL|
```

I want to select only those rows where all Col_B is NULL group by Col_A (i.e. only C should be returned in this example)

Tried

```
SELECT Col_A FROM MYTABLE WHERE Col_B IS NULL GROUP BY Col_A
```

which gives me A and C. Also tried

```
SELECT Col_A, Col_B FROM MYTABLE GROUP BY Col_A, Col_B HAVING Col_B IS NULL
```

which also gives me A and C.

How do you write a T-SQL query to select a group only when all match the criteria?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
declare @t table (id int,Col_A char(1),col_b char(1))
insert into @t(id,Col_A,Col_B) values
(1,'A',NULL),
(2,'A', 'a'  ),
(3,'B', 'a'  ),
(4,'C',NULL),
(5,'C',NULL)

select Col_A from @t group by Col_A having MAX(Col_B) is null
```

Because `MAX` (or `MIN`) can only return `NULL` if *all* of the inputs were `NULL`.

Result:

```
Col_A
-----
C
```

---

Similarly, if you wanted to check that all of the values where all some *specific*, non-`NULL` value, you could check that by first confirming the the `MIN()` and `MAX()` of that column were *equal* and then checking either one of them against the sought for value:

```
select Col_A from @t group by Col_A
having MAX(Col_B) = MIN(Col_B) and
       MIN(Col_B) = 'a'
```

Would return just `B`, since that's the only group where *all* input values are equal to `a`.

Comment: Really great idea in using MAX and MIN! Thanks so much!